# Why string or object type don't support nullable reference type?

Tags: c#, nullable

Look into following code block:

```
//Declaring nullable variables.
//Valid for int, char, long...
Nullable<int> _intVar;
Nullable<char> _charVar;

//trying to declare nullable string/object variables
//gives compile time error. 
Nullable<string> _stringVar;
Nullable<object> _objVar;
```

While compiling code compiler gives following error message:

> The type 'string'/'object' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable'

I read it several times but still unable to understand. Can anyone clarify this? Why `object` or `string` dont support nullable reference type?

Comment: Because yiu can assign null directly: String value = null; Object o = null; On the contrary, you can't to this with strcutures, e.g. int = null; is a compile time error

Comment: Because they're already nullable? `string _stringVar = null;` compiles fine.

Comment: you can't concatenate null strings for example

Comment: @WeylandYutani: What do you mean by that, and how is it relevant?

Comment: @WeylandYutani yes you can; the result is well defined (all `null` strings act the same as `""` as far as concatenation is concerned)

Comment: oh sorry i was wrong :( i just tried it

Comment: Also, just for completion sake, you may or may not be aware of this, but you can use a question mark to define nullables, eg. `Nullable<int>` is the same as `int?`. This will not allow you to write `string?`, but that's well explained by the answers.

Comment: You could use char?[] and char[] (or char* even) if you feel the distinction is important. Char[]s aren't very friendly though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`object` and `string` are reference types, so they're already nullable. For example, this is already valid:

```
string x = null;
```

The [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) generic type is only for cases where `T` is a non-nullable *value* type.

In the declaration for `Nullable<T>` there is a constraint on `T`:

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
```

That `where T : struct` is precisely the part that constrains `T` to be a non-nullable value type.

Comment: And the constraint is probably there to make sure you don't do anything too crazy. .NET has tons of optimizations to make sure using Nullable isn't a significant performance hit. After all, Nullable is itself a value-type (a struct), but you can't do a nullable of a nullable - the compiler probably has an extra validation somewhere not covered by C# generic constraints - just using decompiled code of Nullable will let you do a eg. `MyNullable<MyNullable<int>>`.

Comment: @Luaan: No, there's no "extra validation" here: `where T : struct` already prevents `Nullable<Nullable<int>>` because `Nullable<int>` isn't a non-nullable value type. I suspect your decompiled version didn't include the constraint.

Comment: @Luaan the "extra validation" there is specifically for the `Nullable<T>` case - the `where T : struct` explicitly has rules about that, which do not apply to `MyNullable<T>` / `MyNullable<MyNullable<T>>` - but it **would** prevent `MyNullable<Nullable<T>>`.

Comment: The constraint is there. The signature is `public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct`, ie. it's also a struct, and thus a valid value-type. What's wrong with my logic/understanding?

Comment: @Luaan: Your assumption that `where T : struct` means that `T` just needs to be a struct. It must be a *non-nullable* value type. `Nullable<int>` isn't a non-nullable value type. But yes, thinking about it, your `MyNullable<T>` wouldn't be considered a nullable value type, so both `MyNullable<MyNullable<int>>` and `Nullable<MyNullable<int>>` would be okay, but `MyNullable<Nullable<int>>` wouldn't.

Comment: `Nullable<T>` and `?` both use to define nullable stuct type, but still don't know how `?` equivalent to  `Nullable<T>`. I mean how compiler identify defined struct type is nullable by `?` ?

Comment: @AnkushMadankar: The `?` suffix is *just* C# shorthand for `Nullable<T>`. So you can write: `int? x = new Nullable<int>(10);` for example. It's a bit like `float` being an alias for `System.Single`.

Comment: Yeah, that's true, but where is that little bit of extra information hidden? I can't find any difference between my class and `System.Nullable` even in IL decompilation. So is it something that's omitted even from ILDASM, or is it something hardcoded somewhere in the .NET infrastructure? You're right that it isn't the C# compiler, since if I try to create the type `Nullable<Nullable<int>>` dynamically using reflection, it still throws. But where is it? :D

Comment: Yes I know that, something I am asking which Luaan added in his last comment.

Comment: @Luaan: It's not "hidden" - it's part of the CLI and C# specifications. For example, it's in ECMA-335 section II.10.1.7: "valuetype is a special-purpose constraint that constrains Id to being a value type, except that the type shall not be `System.Nullable<T>` or any concrete closed type of `System.Nullable<T>`"

Comment: Oh, great. So it *is* some hardcoded special case, not information hidden in the nullable type itself. In other words, there's no way whatsoever to mimic the way the type constraint works in Nullable for your own class.

Comment: @Luaan: Right, yes. I think I misunderstood your initial comment; it's "known" by the compiler that a `where T : struct` constraint excludes `Nullable<T>`, but the constraint *on `Nullable<T>` itself* is just the regular `where T : struct`.

Answer (score 4):

`Nullable<T>` is defined as:

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
```

meaning: it only works on value-type `T` (excluding `Nullable<TSomethingElse>` itself).

You cannot use `Nullable<T>` on reference-types (or on `Nullable<T>`), but you don't need to since all reference-types (including `object` and `string`) are already "nullable", in that you can assign `null` to them.

Answer (score 3):

string and object **are** reference types, and therefore are "nullable" already. The `Nullable<T>` type exists as a wrapper around *value types* that don't support `null` out of the box.

```
string myString = null //fine
int myInt = null //compiler error
```